# AudioKit EzAudioPlayer Background playback

Tags: swift, background, avaudiosession, audiokit

hello i am using PandoraPlayer Library as my music player it uses AudioKit for playback and it does not support background playback anyone knows how to enable session catagory playback for audio kit?